# 'Can grow' property mashup table structure in Crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, crystal-reports

I am new at Crystal report and I am tried to generate pdf file using Crystal report. I have used "Can grow" size for GeneratedEntryDebit and GeneratedEntryCredit fields.

[Crytal report format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqWRJ.png)

But it is mashup in PDF file. I want to display clear table in PDF. I have attached the table screen shot also with this.

[PDF format of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8mXa.png)

I have used the same size and font for the all fields but only difference with "Can grow" field.

If Any one can help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: Select the line and click on "format line" and then select "Move to bottom of section when printing."  Then the line will move with the text.

Comment: Did you align the fields correctly?